# cannot perform same activity more than twice

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, passive-voice

Which is the correct statement?

> - Once the installation finished, click on start.
> - Once the installation has finished, click on start.
> - Once the installation has been finished, click on start.

Comment: Which one do you thinks is correct, and why? This link may help you to decide: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/past-tense

Comment: _Once the installation is finished, click Start._

Comment: All three have the same meaning, that is to click *after* the installation has finished. *Is* is the most natural one since it described the *current state* at the time and means "immediately after the installation, click on start", the other alternatives do not have the same feeling of urgency.

Comment: I personally would not say all three have the same meaning. The first one is not grammatically correct. But this may just be a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving an instruction on what do to after something *in the future* has occurred.

The correct option is:

> <s>Once the installation finished, click on start</s>
>   Once the installation has finished, click on start
>   <s>Once the installation has been finished, click on start</s>

You must say "once the installation *has* finished" because at the time of the instruction, it has not yet finished.

The expression "has been" is only appropriate is something has been used up by something or someone.

For example, you might say:

> "After the cake has been finished, clear the plate away"

That's because the cake didn't do the finishing - it *was* finished by those who ate it.

As you are speaking directly about the installation, which completes by itself, just say it "has finished".